# Executing custom code on click on DGML node

Tags: powershell, nuget, dgml

Is it possible to execute a piece of C# code when the node of a DGML diagram is double clicked?
It is possible to navigate to an url, I could create a local web site (on127.0.0.1) where you request an URL which executes a command. Problem is that I would like to execute a PowerShell function in the NuGet console...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute custom code, since that would make DGML a security threat when you send it in email, but you can put a “Reference” attribute containing a URL value on a node and when the user double clicks that node the URL is opened. For more information, see [How to: Edit and Customize Graph Documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee842619.aspx#AddReferences).